# Why use identity/dns in WCFconfig

Tags: wcf

****Hi,
I just want to know why we use the below configuration in WCF.

identity dns value="localhost"

Should we remove this identity during QA/Production deployemnt.**
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

From the Client perspective you need to always do the service authentication to ensure that the client that the service it calls really is the service it tries to call. This becomes even more important with clients which call over the Internet. Imagine if a malicious party subverts the client's DNS service. This way you are exposed to hijacking of your clients calls.